# Ubuntu 19.10 Theme Shell Gnome Tweaks

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, 19.10

I'm trying to figure out what Gnome Tweaks is looking for under Shell selection. All of the directions on Google searches act like it just magically works without actually saying what file it searches. In 18.4 it did work. In 19.10 it doesn't. So I am just trying to remedy the Theme files so the Shell can pick up on them?

Edit: to clarify, The files in each theme directory under `/home/user/.themes/` and `/usr/share/themes`  don't seem to have a file the Gnome Tweaks extension will accept for the Shell dialog? I notice some menus pop up white under dark themes, and I'd also like to edit the dash font. I have edited the `gnome-shell.css` file in the theme I finally got to recognize from Gnome Tweaks. But it has no effect on the fonts in the dash/dock bar? I got it to work so easily in 18.04.04 but 19.1 I'm at a loss.

[image: show Desktop]

Comment: What files? What are you *actually* trying to achieve? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: My edits to the css files have me a bit bewildered why they haven't affected 19 the same as 18. Just looking for some enlightenment